# Creating a Unique database based on user in Java

Tags: java

I want to create a program in Java that would have unique users and display unique pages for that user. Describing it this way probably isn't helpful so I will explain it as if it were a student gradebook program.

The program would be able to recognize if a student or a teacher was logging on. If a student logs in he/she would be able to see his/her marks for each class in a table and be able to see the nights homework. If a teacher logs on the program would display a list of students in a table that the teacher would then be able to mark the student absent or present. In a table below that the teacher would be able to manipulate the students grades and in a form below that the teacher would be able to create homework assignments. When the teacher clicks the update button, they would be able to push the data to the students and the student grade and homework page would be simultaneously updated.

Would this be possible in a java web app and if so where would I start?

Sorry for the long droning example.

Comment: Do *not* create "unique databases". Instead, simply add the relevant keys in the tables to create "partitions" - examples would be "Student ID" and "Teacher ID"/"Course ID", etc. The data-access layer itself can be used to restrict access - as can Database Permissions and Views (eg. students may never be able to access some data that teachers can) - and to expose high-level actions. This "push" is then simply changing the relevant database state and, as a separate process, ensure that the relevant client UI is updated.

Comment: "Is it possible?" -> yes. "Where should I start?" -> by learning about databases probably.

Comment: So what language would be best for that?